# Random selection of audio files (onclick effect)

Tags: html, audio, random, onclick, click-counting

I've suceeded in adding an onclick audio effect to my clickcounter image, but I was wondering, is there any way to make a random selection of sounds, instead of one sound? When I click my image, the amount of times the image has been clicked appears, and a sound plays, but I would like for it to play a different (random) audio file on every click (from a selection I have)

these are the scripts I have for my button so far

**Javascript**

```
function clickCounter(){
     var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
     audio.play();
     if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
         if (localStorage.clickcount)
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
         }
         else
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=1;
         }
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<center><b>You have clicked the poop
         </b>"+ localStorage.clickcount + "<b> times!</b></center>";
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="I'm sorry to inform you that your browser
         does not support this web storage... I guess you could say that your browser is...
         shit! awwww yeaahh!";
     }
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center>
     <font face="chiller" color="#603913" "font size="300" <align="center"><b>Click the
     poop!</b>
</center>
<center>
    <p><picture onclick="clickCounter()"><picture
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('touch').play()"><img src="poop.png"></button></p>
</center>
<audio id="audio" src="fart-01.wav"></audio>
<audio id="touch" src="sticky goo.wav"></audio>
<div id="result"></div>
```

How would I script this? I understand that i would have to intertwine it with my current onclick function, and also that I would have to make a table, perhaps with tr or td tags. Could someone please help me with this? I can't make it work.

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: What makes you think you need to add a table? (I ask because I think I misunderstood part of your problem.)

Comment: My IT teacher said it could work that way. I, for my own part, am really confused about this whole script

Comment: As a general strategy for understanding the script, try to delete and simplify the parts you don't understand, and see if the parts you think you do understand still work. If you didn't write the script yourself, but were given it for homework, you should really explain that to us: it makes it easier to help you (if we can.)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a switch case for this one.

you generate a random number with for example

```
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
```

then you can use the switch case to select one random sound of the N possibilities you generete with the random number.

Like

function setSound() {

```
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        setSound1;
        return sound;
        break
    case 2:
         setSound2;
        return sound;
        break
    case 3:
         setSound3;
        return sound;
        break
    }
}
```

and then add the returnd value to you code where you want to play the sound.

In this case you need to return the name of the sound file which you chose random from the swtich case.

Comment: I understand the concept, and It's brilliant! but I'm unsure as to how to script it into what I've already got. Do i write my src after setSound1; or do i use document.GetElementById("my_audio_file")?
And what is return sound? what do i need that for?

sorry for incompitance, I'm rather new to scripting

Comment: you can either set a file name (setSound1) then return the name of the sound and just use it like a varible in src="soundName". or you could use `document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play()`. maybe this link can be helpful http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

Comment: Could you perhaps make this in jsfiddle? or perhaps send me a mail with a html file, containing what you've got?
My email is Daniel_Romar@hotmail.com.

Thanks for your help! :)